# How to use role-hierarchy in Spring Security 3 with Spring EL?

Tags: spring, spring-security, roles

I want to use @PreAuthorize annotation on service methods with Spring Security. One of requirements is to use role-hierarchy. But by default it is not enabled.

I found that in **SecurityExpressionRoot** class ("the base class for expression root objects") there is a property *roleHierarchy.* The class actually does use this property for methods like *hasRole()* and *hasAnyRole()*.

I suppose that if I supply it with my own **RoleHierarchy** bean I will be able to use @PreAuthorize annotations with hierarchical roles.

How can I inject my hierarchy bean into **SecurityExpressionRoot**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For method security you can set `RoleHierarchy` as a property of `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`, something like this:

```
<global-method-security ...>
    <expression-handler ref = "methodSecurityExpressionHandler" />
</global-method-security>

<beans:bean id = "methodSecurityExpressionHandler" 
    class = "org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name = "roleHierarchy" .../>
</beans:bean>
```