# defining userroles with inheriting rights

Tags: spring, spring-security, rights, security-roles

I'm currently looking into the spring-security framework - great stuff so far, pretty impressed.
However, I haven't found out where or how to define a inheritance of permissions.

e.g. I want the ROLE_ADMIN to have at least the same rights as the ROLE_USER. I defined three intercep-urls for spring:

```
 <intercept-url pattern="/auth/login.do" access="permitAll"/>
 <intercept-url pattern="/voting/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
 <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
```

When trying to access any site nesting from /voting/, while being logged in as a ROLE_ADMIN user, I am being denied. Am I missing something here? I know, I could define several roles for the /voting/* branch, but if I imagine that I might have 10 different user roles in one of my real-life usecases, I can imagine the .xml file to get really messy, really fast.

Can I configure the inheritance of roles somewhere?

cheers

***EDIT:***

Thanks to the great community and their input, I came up with a working solution - it may be good style or not - it works :D

I defined an enum which reflects the inheriting spring-sec roles:

```
public enum UserRoles {
     ROLE_USER(new String[]{"ROLE_USER"}),
     ROLE_ADMIN(new String[]{"ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"});
     private final String[] roles;

     private UserRoles(String[] roles) {
          this.roles = roles;
     }

     public String[] getRoles() {
          return roles;
     }
}
```

I then implemented my own UserDetailsService:

Within the methode

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException { ... }
```

where it comes to adding granted authorities to a UserDetail, I get the corresponding enum value and append all the roles defined by this enum value:

```
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(2);
        for (String role : UserRoles.ROLE_ADMIN.getRoles()) {
            authList.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role));
        }
        UserDetails user = null;
        try {
            //user = new User(username, md5.hashPassword(username), true, true, true, true, authList);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
```

My domain object which is persisted, contains a @Enumerated field with a UserRole - in a real environment, this field is loaded from the DB and the corresponding Roles are picked from that enum.

thanks again for the input - love this community ^^

Comment: The usual model is to enforce this at the configuration level so that admins have _both_ `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN`. That actually allows for finer-grained possibilities too (e.g., admins who can't vote).

Comment: Hm.. good point! So I can actually write my own UserDetailsService implementation and make sure to give the user the right roles there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Spring Security does not support the concept of Roles and Privileges. In Spring security are only Roles sometimes called Authority -- Moreover:  In Spring Security are Roles/Authorities that what in a Roles and Privileges System is called Privileges.

---

So if you want to build a System of Roles and Privileges, then you need to do it by your one by building your own Spring Security AuthenticationManager, and tread the Spring Security Roles/Authorities like Privileges.

@See This Blog: [Spring Security customization (Part 1 – Customizing UserDetails or extending GrantedAuthority)](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/01/02/spring-security-customization-part-1-customizing-userdetails-or-extending-grantedauthority/) -- It is written for Spring Security 2.0 and shows how to implement what I am talking about. It also stayes that RoleHierarchy has some drawbacks, but this article is about 2.0, may the drawbacks are gone in 3.0

Comment: So I have to supply a list with hasAnyRole([role1,role2])? Damn.. not so good :)

Comment: You can have other kinds of authorities than roles. For example, in my application I have local userids described as authorities (though they're not used for role voting of course, they are necessary for other parts of the app's security configuration).

Comment: looks like this answer is not up to date since in Spring 4 the roles and are used slightly different way

Comment: @kiedysktos I will have a look on it

Answer (score 5):

Check out [RoleHierarchy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/hierarchicalroles/RoleHierarchy.html) and [RoleHierarchyImpl](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/hierarchicalroles/RoleHierarchyImpl.html) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515789/how-to-use-role-hierarchy-in-spring-security-3-with-spring-el).