# Creating New Roles and Permissions to urls Dynamically in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

Spring security -how to add roles dynamically and depending on role there url access permission must change and when creating role we have to set url permissions dynamically
ex: for admin he can access all urls 
and when i am creating another role like support i can set which urls he can access dynamically

Comment: spring security can do that , what have you tried so far ?

Comment: spring security can to that in static wahy i know but dynamically possible ?

Comment: yes you can assign roles to user's dynamicly

Comment: oh please send me link to example to tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is specifically what Spring authorization handles.
You can use Spring expressions like -

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PERM_ADD')")
@RequestMapping("/add")
public String add() {
  ...
}
```

Here is the documentation -
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/authorization.html

You may want to implement something like this example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60251931/1308685

Where the user roles are mapped to more granular permissions.